# Inverse laplace of a function that doesn't appear in a table

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm trying to compute

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \frac{11s+4}{s^2+2s+2}$$

The best I know to do is rewrite it as:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \frac{11s+4}{(s+1)^2+1}$$

Comment: Good start. Now write $11s + 4 = 11(s+1) - 7$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to post my own solution in a little bit from your hint

Comment: Unfortunately, I am just not seeing it. I get that the resulting fraction is $\frac{11(s+1)-7}{(s+1)^2+1}$. From here I'm lost

Comment: Can you find $\mathcal{L}^{-1} \frac{(s+1)}{(s+1)^2 + 1}$? And $\mathcal{L}^{-1} \frac{1}{(s+1)^2 + 1}$? Note that the Laplace transform is linear.

Comment: BUGGER! So easy now that I see it. Thank you very much!